# Flutter Navigation (Tab Bar) and Select Drop Down form another page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigation, flutter-layout

I'm Developing Flutter Mobile Application. I want to Navigate another Page(With the Bottom Tab bar as display in the Picture) and I want to select a dropdown within the navigation's page. I think My problem is clear to you.

- I Don't want to push that page.
- And I don't want to duplicate My global Key

I added some screenshots of my app and numbers to understand you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Using a provider you can easily navigate between Navigation Tabs

1. Create a Provider for TabBar:

> ```
> class MainTabProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
>   int _currentIndex = 0;
>
>   int get currentIndex {
>     return _currentIndex;
>   }
>
>   void setIndex(int index) {
>     _currentIndex = index;
>     notifyListeners();
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Wrap you Tabbar with the Consumer

> ```
> @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Consumer<MainTabProvider>(
>       builder: (context, data, child) => Scaffold(
>         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
>         body: _children[data.currentIndex],
>        ......
> ```

3. Change Index from anywhere:

> `Provider.of<MainTabProvider>(context, listen: false).setIndex(2)`